# Free Event-Bus and MQTT-Kafka Bridge Availability for ASP.NET-Core

Tags: asp.net

I am considering the following architecture for an ASP.NET Core WebApp consuming notifications from an MQTT Broker.

[image: Architecture]

- What is best **free** event bus for .NET Core use that I could use to enable this?
- Alternatively, are there any free MQTT-Kafka bridges available for .NET Core? I could then have my scoped service filter the messages for devices registered in the user profile.